# How does Java work with variables when evaluating a statement?

Tags: java

Basically what I am asking is if It's possible to use the same variable in an if statement. Assigning it a new value halfway through the statement so that I don't have to initialize a new variable. I know this is probably horrible practice but I'm just curious if it can be done.

Here is the closest I feel that I have gotten so far:

```java
if(curID + 1 != (curID = myScanner.nextInt())) {
    System.out.print(j++);
    break;
} else {
    j++;
}
```

Sorry if this is a duplicate but I couldn't seem to find anything on it. More than likely because I forgot the technical terms.

Edit: Forgot to say that when I ran it I think it just used the new variable for both instances because the loop just broke. I could be wrong though.

Comment: What type of variable you are trying to use here, static/instance/method variable

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: @John What difference would that make?

Comment: If you write code like this, you should hide it under your bed to make sure nobody knows about it. Don't use one variable to mean two different things, and don't write expressions which rely on multiple side-effects executing in a specific order.

Comment: I am not promoting it but these should work too `if(++curID != (curID = myScanner.nextInt()))` and `if((curd - (curd = myScanner.nextInt()))  != -1)` and `if(curd != (curd = nextd) -1)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no benefit to writing

```
if(curID++ != (curID = myScanner.nextInt())) {
```

versus

```
if(curID != (curID = myScanner.nextInt())) {
```

because the value stored back by `++` will be lost by the subsequent assignment. That you're thinking of doing this suggests you're fuzzy on what these things mean.

EDITED: per discussion in comments, you're also confused about the difference between prefix and postfix forms of `++`. The postfix form evaluates to the value before the increment occurs.

But in any case, the whole thing is better written without the embedded assignment.

```
int prevId = curId;
curId = myScanner.nextInt();
if (prevId + 1 != curId) {
     ...
}
```

EDITED: added the `+ 1` to make the code work as discussed in the comments, as distinct from as originally written.

Your concern that you "don't have to initialize a new variable" is misplaced.  Adding `prevId` costs almost nothing.

Writing it per my suggestion means you don't have to wonder about what Java may or may not do (though you can readily determine it from the online Java Language Specification), since it is now obvious.  And that's the most important thing in programming.

Comment: Sorry. I should've clarified that I needed to see if the curID + 1 was equal to the next ID. I was checking to see if the numbers I was given were in ascending order. Like I said. I know this would make for horrendous and unmaintainable code. I'm just doing this weird thing to see how Java works under the hood.

Comment: Then your original code did not achieve that.  Look up the difference between prefix and postfix forms of '++'.   But writing `curId + 1` would be better.  I will update my answer.

Comment: There really isn't any "under the hood" about this.  Expression evaluation is prescribed by the language specification, and the main rule in operation here is "left to right". But that's no reason to write code that is less clear than it can be.